# Python Django - PostgresSQL Database Awith Amazon RDS Shuts Down After pgAdmin app is closed

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-rds

I am working on a Django project right now and want to use Postgres for my database. I am somewhat confused on how sending data to the database (hosted on Amazon RDS) works. I have it currently set for inbound rules as my IP, as most articles say to do. When I eventually move to production, I'd imagine these inbound rules don't work.

What rules should I use so that users can access the data in the database?

Comment: In the title you're asking about rds shutting down, but in the question your'e asking about security group rules.  Is the title wrong?

Comment: If you set your firewall rules properly when you deploy you project and user strong password, everything will work fine.